# how to remove newline columns in mysql while getting the data from database

Tags: mysql, sql

For example in my form address field is there. It will stored in newlines in a database(If i click enter and add text in address field). Now i would like search with full address search.Results will not getting.here my query is like this

```
select * from contacts where address like '69 TEXT STREET,4th Floor boston 2TN'
```

I saw some posts in stackoverflow. what i used for replacing newlines in a column is

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(address, '\r', ''), '\n', '')
```

if i used like this in my query data is not retrieved

```
select * from contacts where REPLACE(REPLACE(address, '\r', ''), '\n', '') like '69 TEXT STREET,4th Floor boston 2TN'
```

I need exact search results.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should replace newlines with spaces, not with empty string

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(address, '\r\n', ' '), '\n', ' ')
```

because if the user types

```
1 Microsoft Way
Redmont
```

and you search for

```
1 Microsoft Way Redmont
```

you use a space where she used newline. Also, you probably should remove all commas etc. from both the query and the database, to match also

```
1 Microsoft Way, Redmont
```

Comment: This one also i tried. but i am unable to get the result.could you tell me what is the problem.?

Comment: Try printing `SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(address, '\r', ''), '\n', '')` FROM contacts` and comparing with your query. You might find what the problem is. You may reduce the search space by `WHERE address LIKE 'TEXT STREET'` or so, then manually find your address, and then see what's the problem.

Comment: yeah.. i tried like that.I got empty result set if address is stored in two lines in DB. if address stored like a single line i got search results. I am not trimming or removing line breaks while inserting the data into DB.

Comment: I forgot to mention the `%` above: `WHERE address LIKE '%TEXT STREET%'` and use a part of your address that cannot contain a newline (say, only one word) and would return few results. The `%` means you only search for a substring, not for the exact string.

Comment: yes i tried.now it will come. but i need exact text search result.for suppose if i use `REPLACE(REPLACE(address, '\r', '')`, '\n', '')** it removes the second line data in the database. For example **69 TEXT STREET,** stored in single line and next **4th Floor boston 2TN** stroed in second line. User will search total string. if i use that command it retrieves the data upto **69 TEXT STREET,** . i need total search string result.

Comment: `REPLACE(REPLACE(address, '\r\n', ' '), '\n', ' ')` should only eliminate the newline character, not the second line. If you print the result of `SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(address, '\r\n', ' '), '\n', ' ') FROM contacts WHERE address LIKE '%TEXT STREET%'`, do you get `69 TEXT STREET, 4th Floor boston 2TN` or only `69 TEXT STREET,`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using '% Search item %' this way ..

select * from contacts where REPLACE(REPLACE(address, '\r', ''), '\n', '') like '%69 TEXT STREET,4th Floor boston 2TN%'